# Failed to load resource in AngularJS project

Tags: angularjs

I have some problame in my AngularJS [tutorial](http://plnkr.co/edit/xl2lw4RWBPfdpRhAxETI?p=preview).

When I try to run the above tutorial I get this error:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

I cant configure why do I get this error.

I use the link to angular library from the `plunker.co` site.

Any idea why I get the error?

Comment: Incorrect reference to angularjs file. Use this: https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-controller` doesn't work in `AngularJS 2.0` anymore, you might want to change to the latest `1.4` version, or dive into `AngularJS 2.0`

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are referring an alpha version of angular 2.0 with wrong path
https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.26/angular.js

Use https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.26/angular2.js

You might want to look at [other 2.0 alpha releases](https://code.angularjs.org/) for angularjs

Cheers!